# Android: Change the source of ImageView present in ListView

Tags: android, image, listview

I have a ListView specified by list_item.xml Now I need to change the Image in my list inside onListItemClick. How to achieve this?

```
//list_item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/play" 
android:id="@+id/img"
/> 
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:id="@+id/txt"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a Custom Adapter to populate my list. Code below is the adapter.

```
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
  String[] objects) {
 super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
 View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
 TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt);
 label.setText(Sounds[position]);
 ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img);
     icon.setMaxHeight(32);
     icon.setMaxWidth(32);
 icon.setPadding(2, 1, 5, 1);
 icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
 return row;
}
}
```

And in onCreate I do the following

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try
    {
            setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, Sounds));
            //Sounds --> String array 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

**Now when any row is selected, I need to change the image associated with the selected view. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: you can implement an [onitemclicklistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) and then react to itemclicks. use this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) to change the source of the bitmap then.

edit 2: it works now with the above method. here is the code.

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adaptview, View clickedview, int position,
                    long id) {

                //TEST SO 4533684
                View subview = clickedview.findViewById(R.id.musicicon);
                ((ImageView) subview).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                //END TEST 
            }
```

as you can see, R.id.musicicon is always the same id of the imageview for every row in the list. but clickedview gives you the exact row where the click happened and in THIS row, there is only one imageview child with the given id.

Comment: No, I don't want a selector. Instead I need to change the image in the selected row.

Comment: shouldnt this work with a selector too? i think you can assign a selector to the image and then the imageview will change depending on the state. edit: ok, no selector possible here as i see now. so check my edited answer. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur effort Markus. But that method will not work here. If I had placed a bitmap with ID, then I can change the source. But inside the listview, every image has the same ID. That method is not possible.

Comment: maybe i can take a closer look at this in my spare time